# How to extract data using async and await function in node js?

Tags: node.js, node-redis, nodejs-server

I tried redis cache implement in node js using mongodb.I set the data in cache.but i cant get the data in cache.how to solve this issue.

**cache.js**

```
async function Get_Value(){
    let response = await client.get('products')
    console.log("_______________")
    console.log(response)

}
```

I got output : true

Excepted output: json data

how to get json data using cache get method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis does not provide a full async await adapter for node.js so usually as a workaround people are promisifying the lib.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);

async function getValue(){
    let response = await getAsync("products");
}
```

An other approach to promisify the entire `redis` library you can use:

```
const redis = require('redis');
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);
```

Now you will be able also to use the methods using `async/await`.

Comment: I could not understand .how to entire redis using bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);

Comment: To not promisify each method separately you promisify all of them at once.